# Ad removing bottom image links

Tags: php, html, css

I have an Adsense ad on top of a couple of images. These images have links and depending on the page query string, it'll display a previous image or not. When having this ad on top of these images, it removes the links on these images. In fact, when you right click you can't even get to those images. It'll say "view frame source" which is referring to the Adsense ad. When removing this ad, the images work correctly and the links work as well. How do I make it so that the images are clickable even with the ad on top of the images?

**HTML/PHP**

```
                echo "<div class='bodyAd'>

                              <script async src='//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js'></script>
                    <ins class='adsbygoogle'
                         style='display:block'
                         data-ad-client= $pub_id
                         data-ad-slot= $ad_slot2
                         data-ad-format='auto'></ins>
                    <script>
                    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                    </script>


                </div>";


          echo "<div class='btns'>";

               if ($num == $maxNum)
               {
                      echo "<div id='prevBtn'><img class='prevBtn' src='/media/assets/prevBtn.png' style='display: none'/></div>";
               }
               else
               {
                     $prevNum = $num + 1;
                     echo "<div id='prevBtn'><a href='$prevNum'><img class='prevBtn' src='/media/assets/prevBtn.png'/></a></div>";

               }

               if ($num == $minNum)
               {
                    echo "<div id='nextBtn'><a href='/stories/$nextArticle'><img class='nextBtn' src='/media/assets/nextBtn.png'></a></div>";
               }

               else
               {
                    $nextNum = $num - 1;
                    echo "<div id='nextBtn'><a href='$nextNum'><img class='nextBtn' src='/media/assets/nextBtn.png'></a></div>";
               }

     echo "</div>";
```

**CSS**

```
.btns{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.nextBtn{
    width: 35%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    float: right;
}

.prevBtn{
    width: 35%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    float: left;    
}
```

Comment: if you want the images clickable you make the ads unclickable which defeats their purpose as clickable ads

Comment: @madalinivascu I don't understand why I can't put an ad on top of two clickable images? These images do not overlap the ads in anyway. In fact there is a good amount of space between them.

Comment: did you consult the dev tools most likely the ads overlap the images , try clearing any floats that you have

Comment: @madalinivascu There are no floats, the floats are only inside the block div. When I place  an ad underneath the images, the images work correctly.

Comment: place  the following css in your site `.bodyAd {clear:both;}`

Comment: @madalinivascu I have tried that, but it doesn't work

Comment: then give a height to the bodyAd `.bodyAd {height:50px;}` if the click works that means the add overflows over the iamges

Comment: @madalinivascu it still doesn't work even with the height

Comment: strange do you have a url i can look at?

Comment: I concur with the idea that the ad takes up all the screen for some reason. Check in your dev tools to see what height the ads really ends up with.

Comment: @madalinivascu I changed that ad height to 500px, and the images work now. But how do I make it so that the ads don't take up that much space?

Comment: @MrLister When I give the a height of 500px in my CSS, the images work correctly. I just don't know how I can make it so that the ads don't take up as much space.

Comment: Who knows. We need to see an actual example of a page with the ads on before we can say anything. Perhaps the ads have a `min-height` or `!important` in their css, but that's just guesswork.

Comment: @MrLister I have fixed it. Since the ads are responsive, they are receiving as much height as they need. I added `overflow: auto` and you could scroll and see the empty white space that was given to the ads. In order to remove this, I added `overflow: hidden` so only the ad shows up and not the white space. The images work and the ad is in its rightful container.